# What audio formats are supported by TTS?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

What audio formats are supported by [`synthesizeToFile`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#synthesizeToFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.HashMap%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E,%20java.lang.String%29) method? The examples I've read always refer to the WAV format, but I could not find a list of all supported formats. Moreover, what are the supported audio files for playback by the TTS engine ([`addEarcon`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#addEarcon%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`addSpeech`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#addSpeech%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) methods)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect all you can get is WAV: staring at [one version of the code](http://nv-tegra.nvidia.com/gitweb/?p=android/platform/external/svox.git;a=blob;f=pico/lib/picoapi.c;h=c4ef8bfc091a1b6ac68f6b4b44ce21df1957ee2a;hb=9ff6c8f6036ea7cfa745a15afb26223bfa20cbe9) it appears that the return type is `PICO_DATA_PCM_16BIT` (see line 656).

Comment: I could try to record using [these formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_file_format#List_of_formats), ie changing the extension of the destination file (for `synthesizeToFile` method), hoping that the extension is not ignored.

Comment: You COULD try that: I anticipate disappointment in your future. The method explicitly sets the output format: it does not read the file extension at any point to determine what it should output.

Comment: Indeed, it shouldn't care: it will write the PCM data into the file just fine. If you open it it won't be readable as a text file, but if you copy it and rename it to a .WAV extension it should play fine.

Comment: I'm reading the properties related to an audio file produced by the `synthesizeToFile` method: _PCM S16 LE (araw), Mono, 16000 Hz, 16 bit per sample_.